# JSON Parsers and adding new attributes to JSON objects

Tags: json, parsing

Question about popular JSON Parsers in different languages (Java, Objective C, Swift, Ruby, Python, etc.):

Do most of the popular Parser/Parsing frameworks tolerate addition of attributes in JSON payloads ?

For perspective, consider a client of some service that produces a JSON response. If I add attributes, I don't expect a client to be able to take advantage (understand) these attributes unless they change code. But I want to know which parsers will actually break (fail to operate, return an error or throw an exception) if they encounter a new attribute.

Example-

Before:

```
{
   "person": {
     "firstName": "Joe",
     "lastName": "Smith"
   }
}
```

After:

```
{
   "person": {
     "firstName": "Joe",
     "middleName" : "Allen",
     "lastName": "Smith"
   }
}
```

If a client written and tested to accept the `Before` version one day sees an `After` version, will most parsers handle it without breaking?  (IOW - Is this kind of change considered backwards-compatible in JSON ?)